# Difference between interface-abstract (not duplicate)

Tags: java, oop

I want to know the difference between the two codes. 
I have a interface: 
lets say :

```
public interface iaminterface {
      void m1();
      void m2();
      void m3();
}
```

First Code :

```
public abstract class iamabstract implements iaminterface  {
     public void m1(){}
     public abstract void m2();  // abstract method .So i need to override this in the subclasses. 
}

public class car extends iamabstract {
public void m2(){}
public void m3(){}
}


public class train extends iamabstract {
public void m2() {}
public void m3() {}
}
```

This code will compile successfully. But this code is same as writing :

Second Code:

```
 public abstract class iamabstract implements iaminterface {

     public void m1(){}

}

public class car extends iamabstract {
public void m2(){}
public void m3(){}
}


public class train extends iamabstract {
public void m2() {}
public void m3() {}
}
```

I don't understand the difference in the two codes. Both codes will function in a similar way. One has a abstract method and another does not have a abstract method, so we need to implement the unimplemented methods of the interface. So , what's the use of writing the method m2() as abstract in the first code. ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only reason you would want to override the interface method in your abstract class is if you wanted to be *more specific* about the type returned. For example:

```
public interface TheInterface {
    Object getTheObject();
}

public abstract class TheAbstractClass implements TheInterface {
    @Override
    public abstract String getTheObject();
}
```

Note that even though the `@Override` annotation is used, the abstract class method actually returns a `String` instead of an `Object`. This does not break the contract that an object implementing `TheInterface` will return an `Object` from that method - a `String` is an `Object`, after all.

However, it does allow you to work with a concrete subtype of `TheAbstractClass` and know for certain that it will give you a `String`.

Comment: Sorry for the bad formatting. I just updated my code, which says that the car and train method extends iamabstract class. Thanks for your answer, i think my doubt has been cleared now. You mean to say that, if you want to be more specific about the return type only then we need to override the interface method in the abstract class, right?
But while overriding we need to keep in mind that the new return type should be a subtype of the original one.